# @RefreshScope side effects - auto-configuration, auto-wiring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-cloud

I am using @RefreshScope annotation to refresh my beans after a change in Spring Config Server. This works fine but it has side effects in some cases.

First case: I have a bean CustomPermissionEvaluator that implements PermissionEvaluator (spring-security) in order to override default implementation (DenyAllPermissionEvaluator).

```
import org.springframework.security.access.PermissionEvaluator;

@Component
public class CustomPermissionEvaluator implements PermissionEvaluator {

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Object targetDomainObject, Object permission) {
```

If I annotate CustomPermissionEvaluator with @RefreshScope, Spring no longer take it into account and the default implementation is chosen over this custom implementation.

Second case: I have the following bean:

```
@Bean
@Profile("enable_mongo_ssl")
public MongoClientOptions mongoClientOptions() {
    return getMongoClientOptionsBuilder()
            .build();
    }
```

If I annotate it with @RefreshScope, MongoAutoConfiguration is not taking it when building MongoClient and default mongoClientOptions with no certificate is instead used.

Last case:
I have an object mapper defined:

```
@Bean
@Primary
public ObjectMapper defaultObjectMapper() {
    return ObjectMapperProvider.defaultObjectMapper();
}
```

If I annotate it with @RefreshScope, I get the following error:

```
more than one 'primary' bean found among candidates: [defaultObjectMapper, jacksonObjectMapper]
```

I guess those examples have to do with the fact the @RefreshScope annotation causes the bean to be proxied.
But is there a clean way to keep using this annotation and make those features work?

Comment: I tried the `PermissionEvaluator` example and it worked for me. I think you might have to provide an actual minimal sample application to reproduce. It's probably something to do with the way you construct the beans, and not the code above directly.

Comment: Will try with a clean project. Will let you know. Thanks.

Comment: @DaveSyer  I created a simple application to reproduce it: https://github.com/gitmykeul/spring-cloud-example. It has a Config Service, a client with a simple controller with PreAuthorize and a CustomPermissionEvaluator with or w/o RefreshScope.